# UIMenuController is not working in ios6

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios6

I am working on ios6, and am developing one iphone app. In this app I am using `UIMenuController` for copy option. The Copy option is working fine in ios5, but it is not working in ios6. I can't display the copy option.

Below I have attached my code. Please somebody help me how to solve this issue.

```
- (BOOL) canPerformAction: (SEL) action withSender: (id) sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {  
        return (action == @selector(copy:)); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL) canPerformAction: (SEL) action withSender: (id) sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {  
        return (action == @selector(copy:)); 
    }
} 
return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

try this, hope it helps!!